# Run dask scheduler and workers in Amazon's ECS (Fargate)

Tags: docker, dask, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I tried to run a scheduler and workers docker containers on Amazon's ECS.
I'm using this example:
https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/setup/docker.html

The scheduler works perfectly, I successfully connected to it from my local machine:

```
distributed.scheduler - INFO - Remove client Client-0ae5b0fa 
distributed.scheduler - INFO - Close client connection: Client-0ae5b0fa 
distributed.scheduler - INFO - Remove client Client-0ae5b0fa 
distributed.core - INFO - Starting established connection 
distributed.scheduler - INFO - Receive client connection: Client-0ae5b0fa
```

I try to run the worker the same way, with this command:

> dask-worker tcp://SCHEDULER_PUBLIC_IP:8786

The worker is writing these logs and exits:

```
+ exec 'dask-worker tcp://SCHEDULER_PUBLIC_IP:8786'
/usr/bin/prepare.sh: line 30: /dask-worker tcp://SCHEDULER_PUBLIC_IP:8786: No such file or directory
+ '[' '' ']'
no environment.yml
+ '[' -e /opt/app/environment.yml ']'
+ echo 'no environment.yml'
+ '[' '' ']'
+ '[' '' ']'
```

I expected the worker to connect to the scheduler, because the same commands worked when I tried them on an EC2 instance. Also, I tried doing this with all ports open to tcp connections and still nothing.

Environment:

- Dask docker container version: 6bfa3b19b4be (1 AUG 2021) (latest)
- Fargate version: 1.4.0 (latest)
- Container has 2 vCPUs, 4 Gb memory

Comment: From what I am reading I assume you are building two ECS services (one for the scheduler and one for the worker) off of the container images linked at https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/setup/docker.html? Also I understand that the scheduler works but the worker doesn't? Specifically the container in the worker exits with that error message? From the message it looks like the script is trying to read a variable to get to the scheduler. Is it possible that `SCHEDULER_PUBLIC_IP` should be `$SCHEDULER_PUBLIC_IP` instead? And you need to pass that variable to the worker service/task?

Comment: All in all I find hard to bridge what's in the link (docs.dask.org/en/latest/setup/docker.html) with what you are deploying.

Comment: @mreferre thank you for commenting. Yes, I built two services, using daskdev/dask:latest. Again you understood correctly, the scheduler works but the workers doesn't. I changed the original error message to not show the actual public IP of the machine, it is not an environment variable.

Comment: The command I'm using in the scheduler's task definition: dask-scheduler .  

The command I'm using in the worker's task definition: dask-worker tcp://1.2.3.4:8786 .  

For testing purposes , I run the scheduler taks, write down its public IP, and use it in the worker's definition. I understand I should use service discovery, buy I'll handle this later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my command was not comma delimited. it was:

```
dask-worker 1.1.1.1:8786
```

it is supposed to be:

```
dask-worker,1.1.1.1:8786
```

in order for docker to understand these are different arguments:

> **Command** ["dask-worker","1.1.1.1:8786"]